# Simulator places images with constant CGPoint to the right of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, image, simulator

Using: OS 10.11.5, Xcode 7.3.1 and Simulator 9.3
2 images and 2 labels (none with constraint) appear shifted right on the simulator, no vertical change. Setting positioning constraints doesn't help. Inspite of this, the project work. 
After working on the project, now an image that should be near the centre appears also to the right when simulating. I've commented out everything that has to do with this image leaving it at a constant CGPoint(x: 375.0, y: 333.0) and still it appears on the right margin. Please, what can I do?

Comment: Show us your constraints.

Comment: You need to perform autolayout.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur "Setting positioning constraints doesn't help"

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, my wrong

Comment: I just discovered that the Storyboard has a width of about 550 and the Simulator has a width of about 360 (both are set to iPhone 6).  Doesn't seem logical. I made the needed relocations and now the iPhone image is correct.    In regard to the constant GCPoint, x: should be 175 (my bad).           Can the discrepancy between Storyboard an iPhone be corrected?

Comment: If I don't use constraints, images and labels all go to the top.